# How to fix Plroblem Bootstrap3 col-md-4 and col-lg-4 not working at IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie-developer-tools, ie8-browser-mode, ie8-webslice

I am Using Bootstrap 3 class col-md-8 and the col-md-4.but the left column will not pull all the way to the left.

The original page works on Safari, and Firefox on Mac and Windows. IE8 does not work using header section html5shiv.js, responds.js,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Store Sale</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Pushy is an off-canvas navigation menu for your website.">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
       <!--End Bootstrap-->
       <!--Font Awesome-->
     <link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!--End Font Awesome-->

        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <!-- Pushy CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pushy.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

        
        <!-- jQuery -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <!--DD Search-->
        <script src="js/jquery.ddslick.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <!--End DD-->
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css">
       <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Pushy Menu -->
        <nav class="pushy pushy-left">
            <ul>
                <li class="pushy-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="pushy-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="pushy-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Submenu 3</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="pushy-submenu">
                    <a href="#">Submenu 4</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                        <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="pushy-link"><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <!-- Site Overlay -->
        <div class="site-overlay"></div>

        <!-- Your Content -->
                    <!-- Menu Button -->
            <div class="headerT">

<div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="headerL menu-btn"><a href="#" class="menutoggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
 <div class="headerM">
  <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo_1.gif" alt="Store Sales" class="img-responsive"></div> 
  <div class="navM">
  
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/stores.png" alt="Stores" class="fade"><br/>Stores</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/brands.png" alt="Brands" class="fade"><br/>Brands</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/offers.png" alt="Offers" class="fade"><br/>Offers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/loyalty-cards.png" alt="Loyalty Cards" class="fade"><br/>Loyalty Cards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/vouchers.png" alt="Vouchers" class="fade"><br/>Vouchers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/favourites.png" alt="Favourites" class="fade"><br/>My Favourites</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/shopoholic.png" alt="Shopoholic" class="fade"><br/>Shopoholic</a></li>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </ul>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
<div class="headerR"><a href="#" class="search"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!--Drop Down Animation  Search Box-->
<div class="searchM">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-3 searchL">
   <div id="demoBasic" class="dd-container">
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 searchMB searchMM">
      <div id="searchMM">
   </div>
      
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 searchF searchR">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-dan">Search</button>
     <i class="fa fa-filter" aria-hidden="true"></i>Filter Search
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!--End Drop Down Animation Search Box-->
<div>
<p>  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like</p>
</div>
        <!-- Pushy JS -->
        <script src="js/pushy.min.js"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $( ".search" ).click(function() {
    $( ".searchM" ).toggle( "blind" );
});
  
});
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this should be ie9, so it just can search < ie9.

```
      <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie8.css">
       <![endif]-->
```